# accountExpires properties not changing format

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

so i have this one liner that returns specific properties about all users in AD.

My issue is that it keeps returning the "accountExpires" field blank and i don't know why.

If i change the script to just return the property un-formatted it work, but it's not exactly readable.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select Name,Enabled,whenCreated,whenChanged,@{N='accountExpires';E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.accountExpires)}},@{N='LastLogon'; E={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActiveDirectory module has what is, to me, an annoying feature. Rather than convert dates in fields that contain dates (such as accountExpires) they have presented a second property with a similar-ish name which contains the converted value.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object AccountExpirationDate
```

This should, hopefully, get you away from the need to spin your own conversion.

Comment: The thing about the AccountExpirationDate is that it has to be a filled in field, the AccountExpires should return a value of 9223372036854775807 Which means the account does not have a set expiry date.

Like so: 
'AccountExpirationDate : 
AccountExpires        : 9223372036854775807'

Comment: No, expiration can either be represented by null or the value you have above. The value above is too large to be converted into a time stamp. This throws an exception: `[DateTime]::FromFileTime(9223372036854775807)`, it looks prettier in hex (`0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`) so either way you'll end up with null in your date representation.

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the Help Chris.

Comment: I always prefer references for things like this, it's either 0 or the larger value for never expires: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396